# Faster SQL Server: insert the null, or skip it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-performance

Simple SQL Server question .. which is faster:

1. Insert where you skip the column (as NULL)
2. Insert where you explicitly insert the NULL?

.... and why?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.myTable
(
     Id int CONSTRAINT PK_myTable_Id PRIMARY KEY,
     Name varchar(200) NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.myTable(Id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO dbo.myTable(Id, Name) VALUES (2, NULL);
GO
```

Please supply reference or benchmark (so that your answer isn't just an opinion).

Thanks.

**PS**: I could run 2 massive loops, and compare the total time, but it still wouldn't tell me why..

Comment: If you care about optimizing such steps, you are clearly focused on the wrong thing.

Comment: I have never bothered to even consider this but the difference (if any) would so minimal it wouldn't be worth spending any effort on it at all.

Comment: [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/), if you really care about this.

Comment: The "and why" is far too broad a question.  I've heard good things about the book "Sql Server Internals".

Answer (score 8):

This makes absolutely no difference in the performance.  There could be nano-second differences in the *compilation* of the statement, but the actual work being done is the same:

- The database engine has to log the insert.
- It needs to find the data page for making the insert.
- It has to copy the data for the *entire* record into the data page.
- It has to set the NULL-bit for the record.

Looking up the `NULL` default value is part of what the engine has to do to determine the format of the record.  There could be extremely small differences in performance due to nuances, such as:

- Looking up a default `NULL` value.  And this might differ depending on whether the default constraint is actually defined.
- Parsing a longer query string.

*Neither* of these would be issues if the query is cached.  And the query would be cached if run multiple times.  On a single execution, the difference would be very hard to measure reliably.